# How to fully delete an application with all settings made?

Tags: apt, 10.04, software-uninstall

I installed AWN dock. I tried to change some of the settings and it disappeared.

I tried to completely uninstall it using synaptic and reinstall, but when I launch it I can't see anything. It's like it kept the error or the setting that broke it.

It would be helpful to know how to delete the old settings because I also want to install a fresh version of Firefox (brand new).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you purge or remove something, your personal settings are kept. I believe awn's user config files are kept in `/home/yourusername/.config/awn`

Comment: thanks! it worked. i tried it also with evolution, and it worked ( deleting the .evolution and the evolution inside .gconf but how do i know where the config files of every application is located??

Comment: I'm familiar enough with the sorting system to guess the locations, so I don't know if there's an actual list of where the user's config is. Perhaps try searching for the application's name (with hidden files showing).